# os.renames without pruning dirs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use the recursive features of `os.renames`, but I'd like to keep the empty folders of the source; that is, I don't wat `os.renames` to prune the empty dirs. Is there any way to make `os.renames` behave like that?

Example of what I want and what I get:

```
ls /foo/bar/
    abc <-- dir with some files

os.renames("/foo/bar/abc", "/some/other/folder")

ls /foo/
    <-- empty folder
```

What I want is `/foo/bar` to be kept (even if it's empty) after the operation.

Comment: You can just go ahead with rename, then recreate the '/foo' the empty folder.

Comment: @AnthonyKong `os.rename` won't create all the missing paths between `/` and `folder`.

Comment: You might be able to use `shutil.move` instead.

Comment: `os.renames` works for me on OSX. (I can see '/foo/bar' the directory after renames). What OS you are using? Maybe you need to show your actual script.

Comment: @AnthonyKong That is the point. I want `/foo/bar` TO STAY.

Comment: @alexandernst Read my comment AGAIN. I repeat: What OS are you on? What is your full script? Are you doing something more than a mere os.renames?

Comment: @AnthonyKong The script is ran on a Debian. Sorry, I indeed misread your comment. No, this is not a single operation, it's a bulk of operations based on some DB entries. Have a look at what https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.renames says. It will prune empty dirs after successfully moving files/folders.

Comment: Look like it is a new behaviour in python3. I was using python2 in my previous test and `/foo/bar` stays.

Answer (score 1):

Use `shutil.move`

**Set up**

```
mkdir -p 1/2/3
touch 1/2/3/README.md
mkdir -p 1/3/4
mkdir -p 1/3/5
```

**Run**

```
import shutil
shutil.move('1/2/3', 'a/b/c')
```

**Result**

```
$ ls 1
2   3
$ ls a/b/c
README.md
```